# Add Fragment inside View through Draw Canvas Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-canvas

I am trying to implement library https://github.com/eschao/android-PageFlip.
I can manage add new layout programmatically by creating like :

```
constraintLayout.draw(canvas);//add new layout
```

But when i add fragment to constraint layout above, i always met error no view found for id xx.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x3 (unknown) for fragment MapLocationFragment
```

How to add *fragment* to layout inside *canvas*? Reason i want to add *fragment* because i want try add SupportMapFragment in order to view google map.

My Activity class *onCreate()* is :

```
  mPageFlipView = new PageFlipView(this, this);
  setContentView(mPageFlipView);
```

where PageFlipView is from library itself.

```
public class PageFlipView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {

 }
```

Thanks in advance.